# Scheduling: Moore's algorithm

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms

In scheduling we have Moore's algorithm to minimize the the number of late jobs. Because of the EDD-rule (earliest due date first), I guess this algorithm has complexity $\mathcal{O}(n \log n)$. I don't quite understand why. The $n$ in  the complexity is clear because of the $n$ jobs we would have to schedule. But where does the $\log n$ come from?

Now I am supposed to show that it's possible to give an implementation for Moore's algorithm with complexity $\mathcal{O}(n \log n)$. How can I handle this?

Answer (score 0):

The $\log n$ factor is part of the complexity for sorting the jobs by earliest due date which is $\mathcal{O}(n \log n)$.

The difficulty to implement Moore's algorithm in $\mathcal{O}(n \log n)$ is the part in which you iterate over the jobs and move the so far longest job to the end of the schedule whenever a job is late. To achieve this time complexity you must keep a list of so far scheduled jobs sorted by length. The complexity to keep this list up to date is $\mathcal{O}(n \log n)$. Iterating over the jobs has complexity $\mathcal{O}(n)$. Thus, the total complexity is $\mathcal{O}(n \log n)$.